# Retrieve xml from web service using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to write a PHP script that retrieves an xml file from a webservice. I have gotten an equivalent working in C#, but my overall goal is to integrate my final script into Wordpress.

The trick is that I need to add an authentication header token.

In Fiddler, the request looks something like this:

> GET https://service.domain.com/sample/stuff/555/state/PA/page/1/size/10 HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: Fiddler
>
> Authorization: 123456789-123456789abcdef
>
> Host: service.mywebgrocer.com

The C# code that I have (working) looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest request =
    (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create("https://service.domain.com/sample/stuff/555/state/PA/page/1/size/10");
  request.Method = "GET";
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "123456789-123456789abcdef");
  request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";

  HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();


  Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(stream);
  String streamString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(streamString);

  Console.WriteLine("Name of xml document: {0}", doc.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("outer xml: {0}\n", doc.OuterXml);
```

What is the best way to implement this in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), because you want the ability to pass headers.  `file_get_contents` won't allow that.  Make sure you take a look at the [curl_setopt function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for all of the stuff you can do with cURL.

I think you'll want the option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. which takes an array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`.

`CURLOPT_USERAGENT` will allow you to pass a user agent string if you choose to do so like Fiddler does (name it something other than Fiddler).

When you run `curl_exec` it should return the XML from the site.  From there you could use the [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), or whatever you want.

Comment: This does indeed seem like what I want. Thanks! However, I'm very new to PHP, and don't quite understand what they mean by the format of the array. Is it saying the key needs to be 'text/plain' and the value can't be longer than 100, or is this a non-keyed array, and each value needs to be 'text/plain/ and less than 100?

Comment: That's just an example.  Each header you want to send needs to be its own element in the array, like `array('Authorization: 123456789-123456789abcdef')`.  You can tack on additional things if you want by just adding them to that array.